# Approximation question

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, estimation

Cars and buses arrive at a bridge according to the independent Poisson processes at a rate of $3$ cars/minute and $1$ bus/ minute. What is the chance that strictly more buses arrive than cars in a given minute?

Comment: If I set B as the number of busses that arrive and C as showing the number of cars that arrive,I was thinking that if I set C=k, the I would be estimating P(B$\geq$k+1) but I'm not sure what do then.

Comment: The distribution of the difference is a modestly useful thing called the [Skellam distribution.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution) One could probably find good estimates by Googling. I do not know a closed form for the probability you are looking for. The answer by Ross Millikan could be used to get a decent estimate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to sum over $k$.  The total probability is $\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(C=k)P(B \gt k)$.  You have $C(k)=\frac {e^{-3}3^k}{k!}$ but I don't see a nice expression for $P(B \ge k)$.  Maybe you are supposed to do it numerically.